# I have got a nullpointer exception

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

**hi i have created an application in android but on running I am getting a null pointer exception**

**I am giving my log cat and java class below I need a better solution to overcome this error**

```
08-23 10:09:57.426: E/AndroidRuntime(3373): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

08-23 10:09:57.426: E/AndroidRuntime(3373): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start
activity ComponentInfo{com.neochat/com.neochat.Friends_list}:java.lang.NullPointerException

08-23 10:09:57.426: E/AndroidRuntime(3373):at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)

08-23 10:09:57.426: E/AndroidRuntime(3373):     at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:2023)

08-23 10:09:57.426: E/AndroidRuntime(3373):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:135)`
```

**Here is my java class**

```
          public class Friends_list extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener{


     private ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();



     private SQLiteDatabase newDB;
      LoginDataBaseAdapter loginDataBaseAdapter ;

        ListView listview;
            Context context;





       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {



    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_friends);
    listview=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);




    context=this;
    loginDataBaseAdapter.getfriends();


        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) 
        {

            Intent in2=new   
                      Intent(Friends_list.this,InboxActivity.class);
            startActivity(in2);
        }



                 }
```

**I am giving my getFriends() function below**

```
              public List<String>getfriends(){
    List<String> FriendList=new ArrayList<String>();
    String selectQuery="select * from   UserDetails";
    db=dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    while(cursor.moveToNext()){
        FriendList.add(cursor.getString(1));
    }
    return FriendList;
            }
```

**I want to display the contents of the table in the database to a listview in my activity**  can anybody help me

Comment: Make sure you have initialised `loginDatabaseAdapter` ..

Comment: At which line and when you are getting error??

Comment: LocalActivityManager.java:135 what is there at this line.?

Answer (score 2):

you are accessing `loginDataBaseAdapter` without initialize it

```
   loginDataBaseAdapter = new ....
   loginDataBaseAdapter.getfriends();
```

Comment: I have initialised it but it still showing a null pointer exception

Comment: You haven't, as @blackbelt has said, you have created the loginDatabaseAdapter and you are using this to call the function getFriends but before you call getFriends you would first need to instantiate it by calling ``loginDatabaseDatapter = new LoginDataBaseAdapter()``

Answer (score 0):

inside onCreate add below line

```
  LoginDataBaseAdapter loginDataBaseAdapter = new LoginDataBaseAdapter(this);
```